# What does the `[` argument mean inside map_df?

Tags: r, purrr

I've come up with the following way of creating a data frame in R using the purrr package:

```
map_df(list, `[`, c("name_1", "name_2"))
```

while I had done it previously with

```
list %>% map_df(~data.frame(name_1 = .x[["name_1"]], name_2 =.x[["name_2"]]))
```

Would anyone explain the `[` argument or guide me to a resource I could use
Thanks

I have already checked out the https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html, I haven't found anything useful, though.
list is a generic list containing n elements, and each of this elements contains name_1 and name_2 elements which will be the colums of my n rows data frame.

Answer (score 5):

`` `[` `` is the subsetting operator. You’ll normally encounter it written like this:

```
x[index]
```

However, in *R every operator is a function*, and `` `[` `` is no different. To invoke an operator as a normal function, you need to backtick-quote it because otherwise R thinks that it should be surrounded by operands. For instance:

```
1 + 1 # is the same as
`+`(1, 1)

2 == 3 # is the same as
`==`(2, 3)
```

For subsetting operators, the rule is slightly different: they are invoked with opening-and-closing brackets but the operator *name* only has the opening brackets:

```
x[1, 2] # is the same as
`[`(x, 1, 2)

iris[['Species']] # is the same as
`[[`(iris, 'Species')
```

Now. Since `` `[` `` is a function (like *all* operators — see above), we can pass the function name into `map_df` like any other function. Think of the above as

```
map_df(list, extract, c("name_1", "name_2"))
```

Where `extract` would be defined as

```
extract = function (x, index) {
    x[index]
}
```

Or simply as:

```
extract = `[`
```

(In R you can assign functions to new names just like any other objects.)

Thanks to the way `map_df` handles formulas, the above is also identical to

```
map_df(list, ~ .x[.y], c("name_1", "name_2"))
```

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I've been using R for a while now, but I had never seen it before